# 'not a valid variable' error when trying to solve 13 equations with 13 variables

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve 13 variables by 13 equations. And here is my program:

```
Solve[{RD == (1.1*NR)^0.6, 0.6*1.1^0.6*NR^-0.4 == wr/em, wr == em^0.2,
  Q == (0.6 NQ^(-1/3) + 0.02 R^(-1/3) + 0.38 K^(-1/3))^-3, 
  0.6 (Q/NR)^(4/3) == w, 0.02 (Q/R)^(4/3) == em, 
  0.38 (Q/K)^(4/3) == 0.04, NR + NQ + NU == 1 - L, 
  w (NR + NU) == wr*NR, C1/C2 == 4*em, 
  L == (1/1.04*0.2^0.2*0.8^0.8*em^-0.2*w)^-0.2, 
  Q == C1 + 0.25 Q*em^0.5, 
  0.25*Q*em^0.5 - em*C2 - em (R - RD) == 0}, {RD, NR, wr, em, Q, NQ, 
  R, K, w, NU, L, C1, C2}]
```

After executing this I get the following message

> ```
> :General::ivar: 1.11396/(w/<<2>>^<<4>>)^0.2 is not a valid variable. >>
> ```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GknA2.png) is how it looks in my notebook. Could anybody kindly answer what's going on?

Comment: Your full set of equations is just unsolvable by Solve. All you could do is use the result of Solve[{NR + NQ + NU == 1 - L, 
     w*(NR + NU) == wr*NR, C1/C2 == 4*em, 
     Q == C1 + 0.25*Q*em^0.5, 
     0.25*Q*em^0.5 - em*C2 - em*(R - RD) == 
       0}, {NR, w, em, Q, R}] to try to find numeric solutions using FindRoot.

Comment: I don't get that error with the code you posted. Did you try to restart the kernel?

Comment: Thanks, Sebhofer. I even restarted computer and then did it again. But this time, the program already keeps running for 20 mins and did not show any results. How come?

Comment: Also thanks for  Rolf's reply. Could u please explain more clearly?

Comment: The error message is probably because you had previously assigned one of the variables. For example, `a=5;Solve[a+b==0&&a-b==1,{a,b}]` gives `Solve::ivar: 5 is not a valid variable`.

Comment: Just as @RolfMertig said (and you've already noticed it), what's really troublesome here is this set of equations may be unable to be solved with `Solve`, you can try `FindRoot`, or, do you have a range for the variables? If so, perhaps `Reduce` is also available.

Comment: Er…where's the definition of `vars` and `eqn`? What's the list at the end of your new code used for?

Comment: 1. vars={RD, NR, wr, em, Q, NQ, R, K, w, NU, L, C1, C2}; 
2. "eqn" is a typo. I changed it to "eqns."

Comment: ……Then what's `NMinimize` used for?

Comment: for finding global min. value with NelderMead  Method.

Comment: So your target isn't just to solve the set of equations?

Comment: Because it is the set of non-linear equation, it seems impossible to get an unique. So I minimize the residual of my object function (like least square method in regression) in order to get approximate value. But actually I am not sure the code is right or not.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with this method…I add the `Thread[vars > 0]` and try `Reduce` but my PC with 2GB memory seems unable to finish the calculation…do you have a smaller range for the variables? BTW, what's the context of the equation? It has a physics meaning or something, right?

Comment: All the variables are economic related variables, and the result values I get should >0. NelderMead is an algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Probably way to hard for Solve; there are, in effect, some polynomials of high degree. One can make them explicit by substituting powers of things to remove radicals. Here is some laborious code to do that.

```
eqns = Rationalize[
  Rationalize[{RD == (1.1*NR)^0.6, 0.6*1.1^0.6*NR^-0.4 == wr/em, 
    wr == em^0.2, 
    Q == (0.6 NQ^(-1/3) + 0.02 R^(-1/3) + 0.38 K^(-1/3))^-3, 
    0.6 (Q/NR)^(4/3) == w, 0.02 (Q/R)^(4/3) == em, 
    0.38 (Q/K)^(4/3) == 0.04, NR + NQ + NU == 1 - L, 
    w (NR + NU) == wr*NR, C1/C2 == 4*em, 
    L == (1/1.04*0.2^0.2*0.8^0.8*em^-0.2*w)^-0.2, 
    Q == C1 + 0.25 Q*em^0.5, 
    0.25*Q*em^0.5 - em*C2 - em (R - RD) == 0}], 0]

exprs = Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}]
exprs2 = PowerExpand[Numerator[Together[exprs]]]
powers = Cases[exprs2, aa_^bb_, Infinity]

base[aa_^bb_] := aa
expon[aa_^bb_] := bb

powers2 = SplitBy[Sort[powers], base]
bases = Map[base[First[#]] &, powers2, {1}]
expons = Map[expon, powers2, {2}]
newexpons = Apply[GCD, expons, {1}]
varrules = Thread[bases -> bases^Denominator[newexpons]]

exprs3 = PowerExpand[exprs2 /. varrules]
exprs4 = Numerator[Together[exprs3]]
```

Here is what we have.

```
{-45482911 NR^9 + 42954893 RD, 
 30555731 em^50 - 48095652 NR^6 wr, -em^10 + wr, 
 K^3 NQ^3 Q^3 + 90 K^3 NQ^2 Q^3 R + 57 K^2 NQ^3 Q^3 R + 
  2700 K^3 NQ Q^3 R^2 + 3420 K^2 NQ^2 Q^3 R^2 + 1083 K NQ^3 Q^3 R^2 - 
  125000 K^3 NQ^3 R^3 + 27000 K^3 Q^3 R^3 + 51300 K^2 NQ Q^3 R^3 + 
  32490 K NQ^2 Q^3 R^3 + 6859 NQ^3 Q^3 R^3, 3 Q^4 - 5 NR^20 w^5, 
 Q^4 - 50 em^50 R^4, -2 K^4 + 19 Q^4, -1 + L + NQ^3 + NR^15 + NU, 
 NR^15 w^5 + NU w^5 - NR^15 wr, 
 C1 - 4 C2 em^50, -155995864 em^2 + 140036747 L w, -4 C1 + 4 Q^3 - 
  em^25 Q^3, -4 C2 em^50 + em^25 Q^3 - 4 em^50 R^3 + 4 em^50 RD}
```

After all this, I expect the following to hang. But who knows...

```
Timing[ns = NSolve[exprs4];]
```