# How to express endogenous variables in terms of exogenous variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I have 11 endogenous variables *(RD, NR, WR, Q, NQ, R, L, W, NU, C1, C2)* and two exogenous variables *(EE, K)*.

I'm trying to find $RD = f(EE, K),\, NR = f(EE, K),\, ...,\, C2 = f(EE, K)$.

Hence, I tried the following code:

```
{e, α, σ, δ, β1, β2, β3, a, ε, η, q, θ, ω} =
   {1.1, 0.66, 0.7, 0.04, 0.6, 0.02, 0.38, 0.1, 1, 0.55, 1.01, 7.7, 0.7}

Eliminate[{
   RD == (e NR)^α, 
   α e^α NR^(α - 1) == WR/(EE q), 
   WR == θ EE^a, 
   Q == (β1 NQ^((σ - 1)/σ) + β2 R^((σ - 1)/σ) + β3 k^((σ - 1)/σ))^(σ/(σ - 1)), 
   β1 (Q/NQ)^(1/σ) == W, 
   β2 (Q/R)^(1/σ) == EE q, 
   NR + NQ + NU == 1 - L, 
   W (NR + NU) == WR NR, 
   (a/(1 - a)) (C1/C2) == EE, 
   L == (a^a (1 - a)^(1 - a) EE^-a W)^- ε, 
   ω Q EE^η - EE C2 -EE q (R - RD) == 0},
   {RD, NR, WR, Q, NQ, R, L, W, NU, C1, C2}]
```

Also, I tried `Solve[{above 11 eqations}, {EE,K}]` and `Reduce`, and still it does not work.

Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Oh…you're still working on this set of equations? (Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/not-a-valid-variable-error-when-trying-to-solve-13-equations-with-13-variables)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for everyone's help. That linked problem already solved.
This equation is based on that question. Do you kindly give me some suggestions if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer.
You could "solve" manually the easy ones and work numerically on the rest :

```
{e, α, σ, δ, β1, β2, β3, a, ε, η, q, θ, ω} =
 Rationalize@{1.1, 0.66, 0.7, 0.04, 0.6, 0.02, 0.38, 0.1, 1, 0.55, 1.01, 7.7, 0.7};

equations //. 
 {WR -> \[Theta] EE^a, 
  C1 -> 9 C2 EE, 
  NR -> (1009899 (3333/7)^(16/17) EE^(45/17))/(61250000000 2^(14/17) 5^(13/17)), 
  RD -> (3333 (3333/7)^(16/17) (EE^(45/17))^(33/50))/(17500000 2^(14/17) 5^(13/17))}
```

Comment: Since David asked for hints, I think this is a legitimate answer.